# TFS Work Item LabelType MaxLength

Tags: tfs

I'm working on a custom work item for a TFS process template and I'm getting errors indicating that the label I used for a group control exceeds the MaxLength value.  Can anyone tell me what is the maximum length I can put on a group label?

Comment: Doing some error and trail, it looks like the limit is 80 characters.  I would like to find some documentation about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you discovered, the answer is 80.  Here's a link to the official documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc339502.aspx

Luckily, the restriction is encoded into the XML schema:

```
<xs:simpleType name="LabelType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="80"/>
        </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

It should fail as soon as you try to Save in the Process Template Editor -- no need for trial & error on the server side.

Comment: That's exactly what I was look for, thanks.  Sure enough, the trail and error was within the Process Template Editor because it doesn't tell you what the maximum length was.